# How to set up a binding from DataGridColumns to a multi-selection ComboBox?

Tags: wpfdatagrid, visibility

I have a `DataGrid` and a custom `ComboBox`. The ComboBox used a `ListBox` to enable multi-select.
I intend to give a `ObservableCollection<Data> Datas` property as the data source for the ComboBox,where `Data` is a class with `string name` and `bool checked`. The problem is how to set up each column's visibility to a corresponding `CheckBox`which used a `Data`as its source ?

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <CheckBox ClickMode="Press" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I saw some post used something like the xmal below, but obviously I do not has any `ElementName` here.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" IsReadOnly="False"
                Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,
                    Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter},
                    ElementName=chkShowPrice}"/>
```

Comment: you want to hide a particular cell or the whole column?

Comment: @pushpraj not for any cells. eg: I have 5 `DataGridTextColumns` and a multi-select `ComboBox` with 5 `Checkbox`. So it will support hiding any column when i click a corresponding `CheckBox`. I am not sure how to set up a binding without `ElementName` for each `CheckBox`

Answer (score 1):

This binding is not straight forward as it looks. Since `DataGridTextColumn` does not fall in the same visual tree as DataGrid, so it is not possible to bind the Visibility of the column directly. However, a bit tricky approach but you may use `x:Reference` for the same.

Here is how we can do it

XAML

```xml
    <!--I added this element to provide the DataContext by using x:Reference-->
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="contextProvider" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DD}"
                x:Name="dg"
                Style="{StaticResource DataGridDemoStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:DataGridDropBehavior></behavior:DataGridDropBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3"
                                Binding="{Binding Symbol}"
                                Header="Symbol"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Data[0].IsSelected, Source={x:Reference contextProvider}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4"
                                Binding="{Binding Ask}"
                                Header="Ask"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Data[1].IsSelected, Source={x:Reference contextProvider}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column5"
                                Binding="{Binding Bid}"
                                Header="Bid"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Data[2].IsSelected, Source={x:Reference contextProvider}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column6"
                                Binding="{Binding Volume}"
                                Header="Vol"
                                Width="*"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Data[3].IsSelected, Source={x:Reference contextProvider}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have binded the items from the same `Data` bound to multi select combo box to the visibility of the columns

changed the following so that the DataContext is available to all the elements instead of just datagrid.

```cs
    dg.DataContext = d;
```

to

```cs
    DataContext = d;
```

lastly to enable the IsChecked binding modify the CheckBox from

```cs
    <CheckBox ClickMode="Press" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="true" Foreground="White"/>
```

to

```cs
    <CheckBox ClickMode="Press" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Foreground="White"/>
```

that's all you need for such binding.

here is the link to the provided sample project [DataGridColumnsVisibilityBinding.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPYnZWRVF3TllXeVU/view)

Let me know if this helps.